# How to avoid repetion with my code

Tags: python-3.x, coding-style

I've written a code that extracts all the words from two files, and only returns the words that are in both of the file.
However, i have done some repetition and that is not considered a good style, so i wondering if it would be possible to avoid this with my code?

```
import re

def print_common_words(filename_1, filename_2):

    try:

        input_file = open(filename_1, 'r')
        source_string = input_file.read().lower()
        input_file.close()
        all_words1 = set(re.findall('[a-zA-Z]+', source_string))   

        input_file = open(filename_2, 'r')                         #Repetition
        source_string = input_file.read().lower()                  #Repetition
        input_file.close()                                         #Repetition
        all_words2 = set(re.findall('[a-zA-Z]+', source_string))   #Repetition

        intersection_list = all_words1.intersection(all_words2)
        union_list = []
        for word in intersection_list:
            union_list += [word]
            union_list.sort()
        for i in union_list:
            print(i)


    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("A file could not be found.")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a method to factor out the duplicated code.

```
def get_file(file):
    input_file = open(file, 'r')
    source_string = input_file.read().lower()
    input_file.close()
    return set(re.findall('[a-zA-Z]+', source_string))
```

Call it like:

```
all_words1 = get_file(filename_1)
all_words2 = get_file(filename_2)
```

Eg:

```
all_words1 = get_file(filename_1)
all_words2 = get_file(filename_2)
intersection_list = all_words1.intersection(all_words2)
union_list = []
for word in intersection_list:
    union_list += [word]
    union_list.sort()
for i in union_list:
    print(i)
```

Comment: But then how do i get all the words from both files into one list?
This is the point where i struggled at.

Comment: See edit. You cannot factor out that code. So simply call it inline as you were before.